# Polish characters are not stored in drop down list from oracle database in asp.net application published on server

Tags: asp.net, oracle, character, oledb, diacritics

I have a problem with my asp.net application. I have some drop down lists that are bounded from oracle database using sqldatasource. I use OLE DB to connect to oracle. When I run my project on my local machine everything is ok, but when I publish my application on server, polish characters a converted to universal equivalents, for example "ń" into "n" and "ł" into "l". What can be a problem? Is it about a version of oracle on the server?

PS. I tried this in web.config:

```
<globalization uiCulture="pl-PL" culture="pl-PL" fileEncoding="utf-8"
       requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8"/>
```

but it didn't help, however currencies have been converted from $ to polish currency.

I hope someone can help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: It could be that the character set of the production database is different from the character set of your local database. Try running `SELECT value$ FROM sys.props$ WHERE name = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET'` on each database. Share and enjoy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But both local and production is the same oracle database. When i connect to oracle locally everything is ok and when server connects to the same database oracle polish characters are corrupted. I a m not an administrator of this oracle database and cannot check settings but we use this source in asp applications stored in other server then the one with asp.net currently and then everything is ok. That is why i suppose thet the problem concerns new server settings or/and version of oracle.  Please correct me if i am not right.